# How can i organize 2 arraylists using a loop?

Tags: java, arraylist

i'm trying to code a grading program using 2 arraylists, one for the student name, and the other for the grades. However, when trying to sort the 2 array by having them ordered by best grade and its student to the worst grade and it student, the output of the grade arraylist is correct but the student one isn't.

For example:

If the arraylist have the names J, A, B and D, whose grades are 13, 20, 7, 11, the sorting result with be:

20, 13, 11 and 7, but the names order will remain J, A, B and D.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<String> student = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<Integer> grade = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        int choice = 0;
        do{


            System.out.println("____________");
            System.out.println("   MENU   ");
            System.out.println("____________");
            System.out.println("1. Add Students & Grades");
            System.out.println("2. Order By Name");
            System.out.println("3. Order by Grade");
            System.out.println("4. ");
            System.out.println("5. exit");
            System.out.println("Select Option:");
            Scanner scanchoice = new Scanner(System.in);
            choice = scanchoice.nextInt();

            if (choice ==1){
                int s;
                Scanner size = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("What's the classe's size?");
                s = size.nextInt();
                Scanner name = new Scanner(System.in);
                Scanner number = new Scanner(System.in);
            for (int i=0;i<=s-1;i++){

            System.out.println("Please enter the student's name");
            student.add(name.next());
            System.out.println("Please enter the student's grade:");
            grade.add(number.nextInt());
            }

            }


            if(choice==2){
                System.out.println("Ordering by Name...");

                int i = 0;
                Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
                for (String num : student) {
                    map.put(num, i);
                    i++;
                }
                Collections.sort(student);
                for (String num : student) {
                    System.out.println(num + " " + grade.get(map.get(num)));
                }



                }
```

This the part related to the issue.

```
            if (choice ==3){
                int temp = 0;
                System.out.println("Ordering by Grade...");
                // System.out.println(grade.get(i));
                for (int i = 0; i < grade.size(); i++) {
                    for (int j = i+1; j < grade.size(); j++) {
                        if(grade.get(i) < grade.get(j)) {
                            temp = grade.get(i);
                            grade.set(i, grade.get(j));
                            grade.set(j, temp);
                        }
                    }
                }
                for (int i = 0; i < grade.size(); i++) {
                    System.out.print(grade.get(i) + " "+student.get(i));
                }
            }
            if (choice ==4){
            }
        }while(choice!=5);
    }
}
```

Comment: If the dual lists solution is required by a schoolwork assignment, say so. Otherwise an entirely different solution would be appropriate.

Comment: Hi, it was a schoolwork assignment. I wasn't sorting the student list. Noticed that earlier today and fixed the issue. Thanks anyways